# Is Eclipse 2018-12 availabe for 32 bit Windows or Linux?

Tags: eclipse

I need to install Eclipse 2018-12 modelling tools on my 32 bit machine.

In the official site it is available only for 64bit machines.

I tried to download Eclipse 2018-09 and then upgrade it to Eclipse 2018-12 but the upgrade process creates p2bu file and deletes the application files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, in Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) the support of 32-bit platforms has been dropped.

See [Eclipse 4.10 - New and Noteworthy - Dropped support for 32-bit platforms](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.10/platform.php#java32-removal):

> Eclipse and eclipse based applications no longer run on 32 bit
>   platforms or 32 bit JVM. Only 64-bit platforms/JVM are supported.

See also [Eclipse bug 536766](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536766).

Comment: Upgrading features of a 2018-09 32-bit installation without upgrading the platform should work as long as the feature does not require a higher version of the platform (which in most cases is not the case). 32-bit support has been dropped to reduce the maintenance costs of the UI toolkit SWT which is platform dependent.